# PrimeNG bug - after closing and re-opening dialog, animation using translateX fails

Tags: angular, animation, modal-dialog, primeng

My problem: I have a primeng p-dialog element, which after opening, shows a stepper with two steps. On selecting the second step, I'm animating a div to slide left, to show the contents of step 2. The animation is simply

```
trigger('slideLeftPanel', [
  state('1', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
  state('0', style({ transform: 'translateX(-50%)' })),
  transition('* => *', animate(500))
])
```

But I've also tried using vh instead of percentage and the left property instead of transform.

When I first open the dialog, I'm able to animate back and forth between the steps with no problem. On step 2, if I inspect the element, I see that the transform property is:

[image: step 2 good result]

But if I then close and re-open the dialog and select step 2, the animation happens but the element resets to show the first step, and the transform property is:

[image: step 2 bad result]

Angular:8.0.2

PrimeNG: 8.0.2

Here's a stackblitz that displays the same problem. PrimeNG 6.0.1 is the last working version... the problem appears in 6.0.2.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zts2bv

Steps to reproduce:

- 1) Make sure PrimeNG is > 6.0.1
- 2) Click "Show" to open the dialog
- 3) Observe that clicking "Show right"shows the right content and
  vice-versa
- 4) Observe that when the right content is shown, div.outer has a computed transform property of matrix(1,0,0,1,-852,0)
- 5) Close the dialog (click outside    of it to close)
- 6) Open the dialog again
- 7) Click "Show right"

Expected behavior:
Animation occurs, right content shows, div.outer has the above transform property

Actual behavior:
Animation occurs, left content shows, div.outer has transform property "none"

Comment: It would be great if you can create a stackblitz for this so we play with it

Comment: @yazantahhan working on it :-)

Comment: check your console you have errors

Comment: @Greg-A no console errors.

Comment: @yazantahhan here ya go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zts2bv

Comment: @earachefl I tried to reproduce it but I believe it is working as expected. Is there a specific scenario?

Comment: @yazantahhan You should see the problem with primeng > 6.0.1. I'll add steps to reproduce in the question.